# extjs4 MVC listeners in controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I'm having trouble creating a listener for the 'itemmouseup' event for my series chart, in the controller.

Controller:

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'monthbalance > chart': {
            render: this.onChartRendered,
            itemmouseup : this.onChartClick
        },          
    });
},
```

if I insert the 'mouseup' event instead of 'itemmouseup' it works fine. But I need 'itemmouseup'. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Update with view extract:

```
        },{
        id: 'card-1',
        xtype: 'chart',
        store: 'MonthBalances',
        title: 'This Year vs Previous Years',
        theme: 'Category1',
        legend: {position: 'right'},
        shadow: true,
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['monthbalance','monthlastyear','monthpreviousyear'],
            label: {
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
            },
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0
        },{
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['month']
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            title: 'this year',
            itemId: 'lineone',
            highlight: {
                size: 7,
                radius: 7
            },
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'monthbalance',
        //  listeners: {
        //      itemmouseup: function() {
        //          console.log('itemmouseup-thisyear');
        //      }
        //  },
        },{
            type: 'line',
            title: 'one year ago',
            itemId: 'linetwo',
            highlight: {
                size: 7,
                radius: 7
            },
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'monthlastyear',
        },{
            type: 'line',
            id: 'linethree',
            name: 'linethree',
            itemId: 'linethree',
            alias: 'widget.linethree',
            title: 'two years ago',
            highlight: {
                size: 7,
                radius: 7
            },
            axis: 'left',
            xField: 'month',
            yField: 'monthpreviousyear',

        }]
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `itemmouseup` event for **[Chart](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart)**. This event is only available for classes that extend `Ext.view.View` or `Ext.panel.Table`

> I think you need to access the series directly and not the chart that
>   holds the series. Set your control to the series itself that you use within the chart and not to the chart.
>   You may do this by setting the *id* property of the series chart so that you can bind the control to that id.

```
// untested but it should work
init: function () {
    this.control({
        '#your-id': {
            itemmouseup : this.onChartClick
        },          
    });
},
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I had it working as a listener that I placed in my view, like in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series), but I really want it in my controller. Can it only be defined in the view?

Comment: I can access the series lines through `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.chart')[0].series.items` in my console, but can't figure out how to access them in the `init` in my controller. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @polarbear I must admit that this is a good question... I don'T have the time to dig deeper and a quick glance at the API didn't helped much. Just one tip; you can defiantly access it by it's `id` property which you should set by your own this case. Even if I do not like setting id's manually in this case it will be necessary.